# Reproducir sonido al cambiar contenido de una tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy tratando de crear una función que reproducirá un sonido cuando algún elemento de una tabla cambie, estaba intentándolo de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#hor-zebra").change(function(){
     document.getElementById('bflat').play()
 });
});
```

Este sería el HTML:

```
<audio id="bflat" src="timbre.mp3"></audio>

<table id="hor-zebra" class="col-6" summary="">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">Ticket</th>
    <th scope="col">Puesto</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd first">
    <td class="first">A083</td>
    <td class="first">MESA 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td>B064</td>
    <td>MESA 9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C028</td>
    <td>MESA 5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo? Gracias.

Comment: Una tabla HTML es un elemento estático y no cambia por sí sola. Tienes que tener algún código en JS que añada filas/valores o tiene que tener algún `input` o algo que permita al usuario realizar los cambios. Debes añadir tu código para reproducir el sonido al código JS que realiza los cambios en la tabla. Muéstranos cómo cambia la tabla y podremos ayudarte mejor con tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Con la API [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) puedes observar por cambios en el DOM y actuar de acuerdo a ello. Ten en cuenta que esta API no tiene un soporte completo por parte de los navegadores antiguos, así que para estos navegadores es muy probable tengas que tener algún tipo de fallback. Puedes ver [una tabla de compatbilidad](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mutation-events) en **caniuse**.

**Ejemplo**

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#hor-zebra tbody');
const form = document.querySelector('#new-ticket');
const ctx = new AudioContext();
const audio = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1gjdrndza3egi9e/communication-channel.mp3?dl=0';

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      fetchAudio().then(buffer => play(buffer));
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(table, { childList: true });

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const ticket = form.ticket.value;
  const place = form.place.value;
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  const tdTicket = document.createElement('td');
  const tdPlace = document.createElement('td');
  tdTicket.textContent = ticket;
  tdPlace.textContent = place;
  tr.appendChild(tdTicket);
  tr.appendChild(tdPlace);
  table.appendChild(tr);
  form.reset();
  form.ticket.focus();
});

const fetchAudio = () => (
  fetch(audio).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
);

const play = (buffer) => {
  const source = ctx.createBufferSource();
  ctx.decodeAudioData(buffer, (data) => {
    source.buffer = data;
    source.connect(ctx.destination);
    source.start(0)
  });
};
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.form-group {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 47.5%;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
.row:last-of-type {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
th {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/4.1.1/es6-promise.min.js"></script>

<form id="new-ticket">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ticket">Ticket</label>
      <input type="text" name="ticket" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="place">Puesto</label>
      <input type="text" name="place" required />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
  </div>
</form>

<table id="hor-zebra">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ticket</th>
      <th>Puesto</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A083</td>
      <td>MESA 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B064</td>
      <td>MESA 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C028</td>
      <td>MESA 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

El evento change solo funciona en aquellos elementos que posen un value como `input, select, textarea`. Lo que necesitas es agregar el evento `DOMSubtreeModified`, que se ejecuta cundo se elimina o agregar un nodo a un elemento.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.js_add_row').click(function () {
    $('#hor-zebra > tbody').append(
      '<tr><td>Test</td><td>Mesa Test</td></tr>'
    );
  });
  
  $('#hor-zebra').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    document.getElementById('bflat').play()
    console.log('beep');
  });
})
```

```html
<audio id="bflat" src="timbre.mp3"></audio>
<button type="button" class="js_add_row">Agregar Columna</button>
<table id="hor-zebra" class="col-6" summary="">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">Ticket</th>
    <th scope="col">Puesto</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd first">
    <td class="first">A083</td>
    <td class="first">MESA 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
    <td>B064</td>
    <td>MESA 9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C028</td>
    <td>MESA 5</td>
</tr>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Se me había olvidado esta forma. El evento `DOMSubtreeModified` se considera obsoleto y no debería usarse. Utiliza la API [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) en su lugar.

Comment: Muchas gracias @AlvaroMontoro